# How to control the frequency of MouseEvents in mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)

Tags: java, events, mouseevent

Example:

When I click and drag the mouse across the screen, the system picks up and registers every MouseEvent until I release. As an example, let's just say that clicking and dragging a certain distance yields 10 events.  I would like for the system to pick up on and register every other MouseEvent, such that dragging the mouse the same distance across the screen will produce only 5 MouseEvents.

Is there a way to control this?  And how does mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) work anyway?  Like, what determines how often it's called as the mouse is being dragged and is that something that can be controlled by the user?

Comment: You can't control how many events are generated. If you state your actual problem, with a proper SSCCE, maybe somebody will provide an alternative solution.

Comment: I may have worded the title wrong.  I don't need to control how many events are generated; I only need to control how often mouseDragged is triggered.  As per the default, I assume it triggers on every generated MouseEvent.  I'd like it to trigger every x MouseEvents.  And I can't post actual code since it's proprietary.

Comment: @chief713: I think that you're unclear on a point. `"I only need to control how often mouseDragged is triggered."` == controlling how many events are generated. Again, *you cannot alter this*. You can only alter how your program *responds* to events.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've already altered my mouseDragged() function to execute on a user-determined counter.  But I figured I could maybe get a slight speed boost if I mitigated the function call altogether.  Ah well, thanks for the input, guys.

Answer (score 1):

On my project I do this:

```
public class MyClass implements MouseMotionListener { 

    private static final long               EVENT_FREQUENCY = 200; //ms
    private ScheduledExecutorService        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private ScheduledFuture<?>              mouseDraggedFrequencyTimer;
    private MouseEvent                      lastDragEvent;

    public MyClass() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        lastDragEvent = e;
        if (mouseDraggedFrequencyTimer == null || mouseDraggedFrequencyTimer.isCancelled() || mouseDraggedFrequencyTimer.isDone()) {
            mouseDraggedFrequencyTimer = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("DragEvent called: " + lastDragEvent.getX());
                }
            }, EVENT_FREQUENCY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```